# Is this code snippet from Rails vulnerable to sqli ? if so what is the payload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, security, sql-injection

Am used to working with PHP and Prepared statement, now when i was looking at the following piece of code from rails ( since i a new to rails and Not sure about the syntax and stuff ) , i was wondering if the code is prone to SQLI injection

Code snippet (controller ) , param q is the value from a search box :

```
def index
    query = %w(% %).join params[:q].to_s.gsub('%', '\\%').gsub('_', '\\_')
    @posts = Post.where("name LIKE ? OR body LIKE ?", query, query).order(params[:order])
  end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is intended to be safe. If it is not, then it's a bug in Rails.

`.where` accepts conditions in several formats. One is a raw string. If you build that string yourself, all bets are off and you are vulnerable.

As some recent documentation says:

> Note that **building your own string** from user input **may expose your**
>   **application to injection attacks** if not done properly. As an
>   alternative, it is recommended to use one of the following methods.

In other words, ALL of the "following" (every other supported way) ways of doing things, are OK.

So if you are doing `.where` with anything other than string parameter, you should be fine.

Comment: the param[:q] is coming from an user , which is not escaped properly , 
Wont this payload affect : 1 OR 1=1 ") -- ?

Comment: Rails does proper escaping. If you are curious, try `Post.where("some bad string").to_sql` and see no escaping. Now try `Post.where("name like ?", "some bad string").to_sql` and see Rails does escape the parameter.

Comment: For extra clarity, what _would_ be unsafe is something like `Post.where("name LIKE #{query}")`, since that bypasses Rails' escaping.

Comment: Also, for complete thoroughness, there _are_ some special conditions under which some of the ways you can use `where` could result in unanticipated (unsafe) results. See for example, https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rubyonrails-security/8CVoclw-Xkk

Comment: @z5h Thanks for the detailed answer , this was the one i was looking  for :D

Answer (score 2):

As long as you don't interpolate within your `where` clause it should be safe. There are some good examples of SQL injection code [here](http://rails-sqli.org/)

Comment: Following the link there it states "Calls using a hash of name-value pairs are escaped, and the array form can be used for safely parameterizing queries". That means unless you don't interpolate within the `where` clause it should be safe.

Comment: +1 This is correct, but it would be helpful to give an example of interpolation, so it's clear what is _unsafe_ , and what _is_ safe.